# Kendo UI Scheduler - Solution to show all days in line such as timeline

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

We are using the grouping property of Scheduler. It is really useful. We show our all technic employees in vertical grouping. 
We want to show all days of month in a line like timeline view.
Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating custom view that extends the desired build-in one and overriding the methods responsible for calculating the visible date range. Such demo can be found in Kendo UI CodeLibraries:

- [Scheduler: Custom view with custom date range and swipe support](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/view-with-custom-date-range-and-swipe-support)